# set data to entity field with query_builder and multiple true

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the following field

```
        ->add('specialProduct' , 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'BSSmartDistributionBundle:Product',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(ProductRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->where('p.active = :active')
                    ->andWhere('p.type = :type')
                    ->setParameter('type', 1)
                    ->setParameter('active', 1);
            },
            'data' => $this->specialProduct # not working
        ))
```

I get the data and store it in session

```
$specialProduct = $form->get('specialProduct')->getData();
$request->getSession()->set('specialProduct', $specialProduct);
```

data :

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object
(
[elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] =>   Array
    (
        [0] => BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product Object
            (
                [id:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 6
                [type:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 1
                [name:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => Starter Pack
                [duration:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 1
                [description:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => Tout de suite
                [full_description:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => blabla
                [price:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 39
                [picture:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => /tmp/php6h3rXK
                [active:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 1
            )

        [1] => BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product Object
            (
                [id:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 15
                [type:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 1
                [name:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => asdsd
                [duration:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 2
                [description:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => asdasd
                [full_description:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => adsd
                [price:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 12
                [picture:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => uploads/product/d978b90215d06fbf569203e7cf2d5aef.png
                [active:BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

now I'd like to check the corresponding checkboxes !?

Same field with multiple false I can set the value with

```
'data' => $this->value
```

I tried

```
'data' => $this->specialProduct # not working (contains $specialProduct above)
```

How can I set those values ?
Do I need to pass an array ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing it this way :

I was storing and passing to the form an arrayCollection

```
controller :
$specialProduct = $form->get('specialProduct')->getData();
$request->getSession()->set('specialProduct', $specialProduct);

form :
$this->specialProduct  = $options['specialProduct'];

'data' => $this->specialProduct
```

instead I use an array with only the ids

```
foreach ($specialProduct as $product) {
    $specialProductIds[] = $product->getId();
}

$request->getSession()->set('specialProductIds', $specialProductIds);
```

pass it to the form with entity manager

```
$this->specialProductIds  = $options['specialProductIds'];
$this->em                 = $options['em'];
```

in the form

```
public function availablespcialProduct($ids) {

    if ($this->em) {
        return $this->em
        ->getRepository('BS\SmartDistributionBundle\Entity\Product')
        ->findById(
            $ids
        );
    }
}
```

and finally

```
'data'     => $this->availablespcialProduct($this->specialProductIds)
```

Still waiting for a cleaner solution !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Setting default values for a form is always done on an instance of  `FormInterface` using `setData` and not as `data` in options array for each form field. [The docs says](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data):

> The default values for form fields are taken directly from the underlying data structure (e.g. an entity or an array). The data option overrides this default value.

If you used `data` option than the form will always have preselected what's in `data` and not from the entity.

So if I understand your code correctly it'd be:

```
$form->setData([
    specialProduct => $request->getSession()->get('specialProduct')
]);
```

Because the stored data in session is a collection of `Product`s.

Comment: so I removed the data in the form,
added setData in the controller,
checkboxes are not checked.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You need to show your code or it's impossible to help you.

Comment: it's a 1200 lines controller :( (yes I know) ! let me try to play with setData. Thanks !